# Why there is a strange white space above the body tag?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>11111111111</li>
    <li>22222222222</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**I find there is a strange white space above the body tag, and the height of the white space is equal to the ul's margin-bottom.** I am confused, that's why?
I use the **Firefox** browser, and it's **version is 90.0.2** (it is up to date).

Following is the snapshot of the page:

[The strange white space above the body tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXLs3.png)

Comment: That's the margin-bottom of your UL that isn't containing the floating LIs. You may wish to look at using flexbox instead of floats for layout...

Comment: @syang Are you serious!?

Comment: @AKX Two margins are adjoining if and only if: - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs: **bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has "auto" computed height**. If I understand you correctly, you mean this？

Comment: Yes, flexbox is the best option. When I discovered it heavens were opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing the floats so you can ignore them to understand your issue.

You have an empty ul having bottom margin. That margin will collapse with the bottom margin of the body then the body is also empty so both its top and bottom margin will collapse and we end with one margin equal to `50px` applied to the body.

That margin will end as a top margin for the body and this is pushing the float content to the bottom.

Here is another illustration to understand what is happening

```css
.box {
  border:5px solid;
}

.box * {
  outline:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:50px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the emty divs are at the bottom. Now add a float element

```css
.box {
  border:5px solid;
  overflow:auto;
}

.box * {
  outline:2px solid red;
}

.box * *{
  outline:4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:50px;"><div style="float:left">ok</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More detail about margin collapsing: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>11111111111</li>
    <li>22222222222</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Use overflow:hidden with ul.